# Proper use of boost Lockguard - Are these two same

Tags: c++, boost, locking

I currently use boost lockguard as follows however I am still a little confused regarding the use of curly braces.I wanted to know if these two are the same

```
void ThreadSafeMethod()
{
   {//Begin Lock
      boost::lock_guard<boost::mutex> lock(mutex_lock_symbol);
      ....
      ....
   }//End Lock
}
```

or this method which eliminates one one layer of curly braces. Is this correct and the same as above ?

```
void ThreadSafeMethod()
{//Locks automatically 
      boost::lock_guard<boost::mutex> lock(mutex_lock_symbol);
}//Unlocks
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `boost::lock_guard` structure implements the RAII idiom (Resource Allocation is Intialization), and thus automatically locks upon construction and unlocks on destruction. When this happens depends on the usual C++ rules, i.e. when the structure leaves the scope that the `boost::lock_guard` was created in.

For instance:

```
void TestFunction( void ) {
     // Do non-blocking operations:

     {
          // Lock the Mutex:
          boost::lock_guard<boost::mutex> lockGuard( mutex_lock_symbol );

          // Do blocking operations
     } // Exit scope the boost::lock_guard was created in and therefore destroy it (thus unlock the mutex)

     // Do more non-blocking operations:
}
```

This just helps you control the number of operations for which the mutex is locked for by creating a new scope in which the `boost::lock_guard` is created. The other advantage of `boost::lock_guard` is that it is exception safe.

In the two examples you have given, because there is no other code outside of the scope in the first example the functionality of the two examples is the same.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, they're the same, as long as you don't add any code after the inner curly braces.

Basically, the curly braces limit the scope in which the lock_guard lives, and thus when it unlocks. Without the inner braces, it will unlock when the function exits; with them, when it leaves the the inner block. However, since in your example nothing happens between leaving the block and leaving the function, they're the same thing.